# Get the latest row based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `material`  -- [HERE IS THE FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7209bd3e316db31d414485212a0c251a)

```
+--------+-----+-------------------+----------------+-----------+          
| ID     | REV | name              | Description    | curr      |
+--------+-----+-------------------+----------------+-----------+
| 211-32 | 001 | Screw 1.0         | Used in MAT 1  | READY     |
| 211-32 | 002 | Screw 2 plus      | can be Used-32 | WITHDRAWN |
| 212-41 | 001 | Bolt H1           | Light solid    | READY     |
| 212-41 | 002 | BOLT H2+Form      | Heavy solid    | READY     |
| 101-24 | 001 | HexHead 1-A       | NOR-1          | READY     |
| 101-24 | 002 | HexHead Spl       | NOR-22         | READY     |
| 423-98 | 001 | Nut Repair spare  | NORM1          | READY     |
| 423-98 | 002 | Nut Repair Part-C | NORM2          | WITHDRAWN |
| 423-98 | 003 | Nut SP-C          | NORM2+NORM1    | NULL      |
| 654-01 | 001 | Bar               | Specific only  | WITHDRAWN |
| 654-01 | 002 | Bar rod-S         | Designed+Spe   | WITHDRAWN |
| 654-01 | 003 | Bar OPG           | Hard spec      | NULL      |
+--------+-----+-------------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Here each ID can have multiple revisions. I want to take latest revisions *(i.e highest of 001,002,003 etc.,)*. But If the latest revision has `curr` as either `NULL`(string) or `WITHDRAWN` then I have take the previous revision and its corresponding value. If even that's `curr` is `NULL` or `WITHDRAWN` I have to again go to previous revision. If all the revision has the same issue then we can ignore it. so the expected output is

```
+--------+-----+------------------+---------------+-------+
| ID     | REV | name             | Description   | curr  |
+--------+-----+------------------+---------------+-------+
| 211-32 | 001 | Screw 1.0        | Used in MAT 1 | READY |
| 212-41 | 002 | BOLT H2+Form     | Heavy solid   | READY |
| 101-24 | 002 | HexHead Spl      | NOR-22        | READY |
| 423-98 | 001 | Nut Repair spare | NORM1         | READY |
+--------+-----+------------------+---------------+-------+
```

I have tried below code, but i'm not sure how to take previous revision.

```
with cte as (
select *,dense_rank() over (partition by id order by rev desc) as DR ,
lead(curr) over (partition by id order by rev desc) LEAD_CURR
from material )
select * from cte where DR = 1 and curr='READY'
union all
select * from cte where LEAD_CURR='READY' and DR=2
union all
select * from cte where LEAD_CURR='READY' and DR=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like filtering and then calculating the row number:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by rev desc) as seqnum
      from material m
      where curr is not null and curr not in ( 'WITHDRAWN', 'NULL' ) 
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also do this using a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from material m
where m.rev = (select max(m2.rev)
               from material m2
               where m2.id = m.id and
                     curr is not null and curr not in ( 'WITHDRAWN', 'NULL' ) 
              );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3a9f0e3bbaaed3c40c5631f0e8c8832) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  It is quite non-traditional to store the string `'NULL'` in a column, because that can easily be confused with the SQL "constant" `NULL`.

Also, your question specifically mentions `'WITHDRAWN'` and `NULL`, but it does not say what other values are allowed.  Obviously, the logic in the queries above might be equivalent to `curr = 'READY'` and you can use that.  The above logic follows your description of the problem.

Comment: OP wants to get parts with latest revisions and previous (`LEAD(curr)`) value.

Comment: @MaciejLos . . . I don't know what your comment is referring to.  If you look at the results in the db<>fiddle, you will see that they are exactly what the OP has in the question.

Comment: My comment is refering to OP question. Take a deep look onto it. Follow the fiddle posted by questioner. You missed that part: `lead(curr) over (partition by id order by rev desc) LEAD_CURR`

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  @GordonLinoff